# Entity Framework SQL Selecting 600+ Columns

Tags: performance, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a query generated by entity framework running against oracle that's too slow. It runs in about 4 seconds.

This is the main portion of my query

```
var query = from x in db.BUILDINGs
                    join pro_co in db.PROFILE_COMMUNITY on x.COMMUNITY_ID equals pro_co.COMMUNITY_ID
                    join co in db.COMMUNITies on x.COMMUNITY_ID equals co.COMMUNITY_ID
                    join st in db.STATE_PROFILE on co.STATE_CD equals st.STATE_CD
                    where pro_co.PROFILE_NM == authorizedUser.ProfileName

                    select new
                    {
                        COMMUNITY_ID = x.COMMUNITY_ID,
                        COUNTY_ID = x.COUNTY_ID,
                        REALTOR_GROUP_NM = x.REALTOR_GROUP_NM,
                        BUILDING_NAME_TX = x.BUILDING_NAME_TX,
                        ACTIVE_FL = x.ACTIVE_FL,
                        CONSTR_SQFT_AVAIL_NB = x.CONSTR_SQFT_AVAIL_NB,
                        TRANS_RAIL_FL = x.TRANS_RAIL_FL,
                        LAST_UPDATED_DT = x.LAST_UPDATED_DT,
                        CREATED_DATE = x.CREATED_DATE,
                        BUILDING_ADDRESS_TX = x.BUILDING_ADDRESS_TX,
                        BUILDING_ID = x.BUILDING_ID,
                        COMMUNITY_NM = co.COMMUNITY_NM,
                        IMAGECOUNT = x.BUILDING_IMAGE2.Count(),
                        StateCode = st.STATE_NM,
                        BuildingTypeItems = x.BUILDING_TYPE_ITEM,
                        BuildingZoningItems = x.BUILDING_ZONING_ITEM,
                        BuildingSpecFeatures = x.BUILDING_SPEC_FEATURE_ITEM,
                        buildingHide = x.BUILDING_HIDE,
                        buildinghideSort = x.BUILDING_HIDE.Count(y => y.PROFILE_NM == ProfileName) > 0 ? 1 : 0,
                        BUILDING_CITY_TX = x.BUILDING_CITY_TX,
                        BUILDING_ZIP_TX = x.BUILDING_ZIP_TX,
                        LPF_GENERAL_DS = x.LPF_GENERAL_DS,
                        CONSTR_SQFT_TOTAL_NB = x.CONSTR_SQFT_TOTAL_NB,
                        CONSTR_STORIES_NB = x.CONSTR_STORIES_NB,
                        CONSTR_CEILING_CENTER_NB = x.CONSTR_CEILING_CENTER_NB,
                        CONSTR_CEILING_EAVES_NB = x.CONSTR_CEILING_EAVES_NB,
                        DESCR_EXPANDABLE_FL = x.DESCR_EXPANDABLE_FL,
                        CONSTR_MATERIAL_TYPE_TX = x.CONSTR_MATERIAL_TYPE_TX,
                        SITE_ACRES_SALE_NB = x.SITE_ACRES_SALE_NB,
                        DESCR_PREVIOUS_USE_TX = x.DESCR_PREVIOUS_USE_TX,
                        CONSTR_YEAR_BUILT_TX = x.CONSTR_YEAR_BUILT_TX,
                        DESCR_SUBDIVIDE_FL = x.DESCR_SUBDIVIDE_FL,
                        LOCATION_CITY_LIMITS_FL = x.LOCATION_CITY_LIMITS_FL,
                        TRANS_INTERSTATE_NEAREST_TX = x.TRANS_INTERSTATE_NEAREST_TX,
                        TRANS_INTERSTATE_MILES_NB = x.TRANS_INTERSTATE_MILES_NB,
                        TRANS_HIGHWAY_NAME_TX = x.TRANS_HIGHWAY_NAME_TX,
                        TRANS_HIGHWAY_MILES_NB = x.TRANS_HIGHWAY_MILES_NB,
                        TRANS_AIRPORT_COM_NAME_TX = x.TRANS_AIRPORT_COM_NAME_TX,
                        TRANS_AIRPORT_COM_MILES_NB = x.TRANS_AIRPORT_COM_MILES_NB,
                        UTIL_ELEC_SUPPLIER_TX = x.UTIL_ELEC_SUPPLIER_TX,
                        UTIL_GAS_SUPPLIER_TX = x.UTIL_GAS_SUPPLIER_TX,
                        UTIL_WATER_SUPPLIER_TX = x.UTIL_WATER_SUPPLIER_TX,
                        UTIL_SEWER_SUPPLIER_TX = x.UTIL_SEWER_SUPPLIER_TX,
                        UTIL_PHONE_SVC_PVD_TX = x.UTIL_PHONE_SVC_PVD_TX,
                        CONTACT_ORGANIZATION_TX = x.CONTACT_ORGANIZATION_TX,
                        CONTACT_PHONE_TX = x.CONTACT_PHONE_TX,
                        CONTACT_EMAIL_TX = x.CONTACT_EMAIL_TX,
                        TERMS_SALE_PRICE_TX = x.TERMS_SALE_PRICE_TX,
                        TERMS_LEASE_SQFT_NB = x.TERMS_LEASE_SQFT_NB
                    };
```

There is a section of code that tacks on dynamic where and sort clauses to the query but I've left those out. The query takes about 4 seconds to run no matter what is in the where and sort.

I dropped the generated SQL in Oracle and an explain plan didn't appear to show anything that screamed fix me. Cost is 1554

If this isn't allowed I apologize but I can't seem to find a good way to share this information. I've uploaded the explain plan generated by Sql Developer here: http://www.123server.org/files/explainPlanzip-e1d291efcd.html

Table Layout

```
Building
--------------------
- BuildingID
- CommunityId
- Lots of other columns

Profile_Community
-----------------------
- CommunityId
- ProfileNM
- lots of other columns

state_profile
---------------------
- StateCD
- ProfileNm
- lots of other columns

Profile
---------------------
- Profile-NM
- a few other columns
```

All of the tables with allot of columns have 120-150 columns each. It seems like entity is generating a select statement that pulls every column from every table instead of just the ones I want.

The thing that's bugging me and I think might be my issue is that in my LINQ I've selected 50 items, but the generated sql is returning 677 columns. I think returning so many columns is the source of my slowness possibly.

Any ideas why I am getting so many columns returned in SQL or how to speed my query?

Comment: What is the table structure and indexes and explain plan? Most queries are impossible to effectively debug without.

Comment: Secondly, and I'm sorry if this seems a little "off" but a cost of 1554 didn't scream at you in an app? This is a simple query a cost of 20 should probably be screaming at you.

Comment: I'll work out adding the table structure and plan to my question. Do you know a good way to pull an explain plan out of sql developer?

Comment: I suspect a screenshot is the easiest way... there's an image upload button in the edit window. Or there's [`dbms_xplan`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/DBMS_XPLAN).

Comment: Man, wouldn't think it would be so hard to get an explain plan to post. it's too long to take a screenshot of and if I try and attach the HTML sql deveoper generates my post gets too long grr. Will look at attaching table structure now

Comment: Everything should be in the question now

Comment: _every column from every table instead of just the ones I want_ That is weird. Are you sure there is not a `ToList()` anywhere in the parts that you left out?

Comment: There isn't any extra .toList() calls floating around. 

The where clause section is really long because I have allot of stuff I add on or not based on the UI. I can edit that in if anyone thinks it would be useful to see the method in it's entirety.

But still, even with a long where clause I don't think that should cause 600+ columns to be selected. I've noticed this before to a lesser extend in a different site but I am motivated to figure out if this is just how EF works.

Comment: Which Oracle provider for EF do you use?

Comment: Hey Gert, My Oracle driver version is 2.112.3.0. Using 32-bit for dev and 64bit version out on the servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a view and having the view only select the columns I wanted and joining on things that needed to be left-joined in linq.

It's pretty annoying that EF selects every column from every table you're trying to join across. But I guess I only noticed this because I am joining a bunch of tables with 150+ columns in them.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion some of the performance is being impacted by your object creation. Try running the query without just a basic "select x" and see if it's the SQL query taking time or the object creation.

Also if the query being generated is too complicated you could try separating it out into smaller sub-queries which gradually enrich your object rather than trying to query everything at once.

Comment: That will be rough because the where clause block is pretty long, but I'll give it a shot in the morning. Thanks for the idea!